# How to quickly jump between starting and ending brackets in Notepad++?

Tags: text, notepad++

I want to get to the beginning of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw4yl.png) bracket, but there are quite a lot of lines in between.
Is there a way to do this quickly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, you just select the bracket and press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>